# Getting SwiftUI wrapper of AVPlayer to pause when view disappears

Tags: data-binding, swiftui, avplayer, wrapper

**TL;DR**

Can't seem to use binding to tell wrapped `AVPlayer` to stop — why not? The "one weird trick" from [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635048/in-a-uiviewcontrollerrepresentable-how-can-i-pass-an-observedobjects-value-to/58635187)   works for me, without state & binding, but why?

**See Also**

My question is something like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697564/how-to-stop-playback-of-avplayerviewcontroller-as-uiviewrepresentable-after-dism) but that poster wanted to wrap an `AVPlayerViewController` and I want to control playback programmatically.

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836235/what-causes-updateuiview-to-be-called-in-this-code) also wondered when `updateUIView()` was called.

**What happens** (Console logs shown below.)

With code as shown here,

- The user taps "Go to Movie"

  - `MovieView` appears and the vid plays
  - This is because `updateUIView(_:context:)` is being called
- The user taps "Go back Home"

  - `HomeView` reappears
  - Playback halts
  - Again `updateUIView` is being called.
  - See Console Log 1
- *But*... remove the `###` line, and

  - Playback continues even when the home view returns
  - `updateUIView` is called on arrival but not departure
  - See Console log 2
- If you uncomment the `%%%` code (and comment out what precedes it)

  - You get code I thought was logically and idiomatically correct SwiftUI...
  - ...but "it doesn't work". I.e. the vid plays on arrival but continues on departure.
  - See Console log 3

**The code**

I *do* use an `@EnvironmentObject` so there *is* some sharing of state going on.

Main content view (nothing controversial here):

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {  // +++ Weird trick ### fails if this is Group(). Wtf?
            if router.page == .home {
                Button(action: { self.router.page = .movie }) {
                    Text("Go to Movie")
                }
            } else if router.page == .movie {
                MovieView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which uses one of these (still routine declarative SwiftUI):

```
struct MovieView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: ViewRouter
    // @State private var isPlaying: Bool = false  // %%%

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            PlayerView()
            // PlayerView(isPlaying: $isPlaying) // %%%
            Button(action: { self.router.page = .home }) {
                Text("Go back Home")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            print("> onAppear()")
            self.router.isPlayingAV = true
            // self.isPlaying = true  // %%%
            print("< onAppear()")
        }.onDisappear {
            print("> onDisappear()")
            self.router.isPlayingAV = false
            // self.isPlaying = false  // %%%
            print("< onDisappear()")
        }
    }
}
```

Now we get into the `AVKit`-specific stuff. I use the approach described by [Chris Mash](https://medium.com/@chris.mash/avplayer-swiftui-b87af6d0553).

The aforementioned `PlayerView`, the wrappER:

```
struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: ViewRouter
    // @Binding var isPlaying: Bool     // %%%

    private var myUrl : URL?   { Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVid", withExtension: "mp4") }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PlayerView {
        PlayerUIView(frame: .zero , url  : myUrl)
    }

    // ### This one weird trick makes OS call updateUIView when view is disappearing.
    class DummyClass { } ; let x = DummyClass()

    func updateUIView(_ v: PlayerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
        print("> updateUIView()")
        print("  router.isPlayingAV = \(router.isPlayingAV)")
        // print("  isPlaying = \(isPlaying)") // %%%

        // This does work. But *only* with the Dummy code ### included.
        // See also +++ comment in HomeView
        if router.isPlayingAV  { v.player?.pause() }
        else                   { v.player?.play() }

        // This logic looks reversed, but is correct.
        // If it's the other way around, vid never plays. Try it!
        //   if isPlaying { v?.player?.play()   }   // %%%
        //   else         { v?.player?.pause()  }   // %%%

        print("< updateUIView()")
    }
}
```

And the wrappED `UIView`:

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    var player: AVPlayer?

    init(frame: CGRect, url: URL?) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        guard let u = url else { return }

        self.player = AVPlayer(url: u)
        self.playerLayer.player = player
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("not implemented") }
}
```

And of course the view router, based on the [Blckbirds](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-environmentobject) example

```
class ViewRouter : ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter, Never>()

    enum Page { case home, movie }

    var page = Page.home { didSet { objectWillChange.send(self) } }

    // Claim: App will never play more than one vid at a time.
    var isPlayingAV = false  // No didSet necessary.
}
```

**Console Logs**

Console log 1 (playing stops as desired)

```
> updateUIView()                // First call
  router.isPlayingAV = false    // Vid is not playing => play it.
< updateUIView()
> onAppear()
< onAppear()
> updateUIView()                // Second call
  router.isPlayingAV = true     // Vid is playing => pause it.
< updateUIView()
> onDisappear()                 // After the fact, we clear
< onDisappear()                 // the isPlayingAV flag.
```

Console log 2 (weird trick disabled; playing continues)

```
> updateUIView()                // First call
  router.isPlayingAV = false
< updateUIView()
> onAppear()
< onAppear()
                                // No second call.
> onDisappear()
< onDisappear()
```

Console log 3 (attempt to use state & binding; playing continues)

```
> updateUIView()
  isPlaying = false
< updateUIView()
> onAppear()
< onAppear()
> updateUIView()
  isPlaying = true
< updateUIView()
> updateUIView()
  isPlaying = true
< updateUIView()
> onDisappear()
< onDisappear()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... on

> ```
> }.onDisappear {
>     print("> onDisappear()")
>     self.router.isPlayingAV = false
>     print("< onDisappear()")
> }
> ```

this is called **after** view is removed (it is like `didRemoveFromSuperview`, not `will...`), so I don't see anything *bad/wrong/unexpected* in that subviews (or even it itself) is not updated (in this case `updateUIView`)... I would rather surprise if it would be so (why update view, which is not in view hierarchy?!).

So this

> ```
> class DummyClass { } ; let x = DummyClass()
> ```

is rather some *wild* bug, or ... bug. Forget about it and never use such stuff in releasing products.

OK, one would now ask, how to do with this? The main issue I see here is design-originated, specifically tight-coupling of model and view in `PlayerUIView` and, as a result, impossibility to manage workflow. `AVPlayer` here is not part of view - it is model and depending on its states `AVPlayerLayer` draws content. Thus the solution is to tear apart those entities and manage separately: views by views, models by models.

Here is a demo of modified & simplified approach, which behaves as expected (w/o weird stuff and w/o Group/ZStack limitations), and it can be easily extended or improved (in model/viewmodel layer)

Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Complete module code (can be copy-pasted in `ContentView.swift` in project from template)

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVKit

struct MovieView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: ViewRouter

    // just for demo, but can be interchangable/modifiable
    let playerModel = PlayerViewModel(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myVid", withExtension: "mp4")!)

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            PlayerView(viewModel: playerModel)
            Button(action: { self.router.page = .home }) {
                Text("Go back Home")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.playerModel.player?.play() // << changes state of player, ie model
        }.onDisappear {
            self.playerModel.player?.pause() // << changes state of player, ie model
        }
    }
}

class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var player: AVPlayer? // can be changable depending on modified URL, etc.
    init(url: URL) {
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }
}

struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable { // just thing wrapper, as intended
    var viewModel: PlayerViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PlayerUIView {
        PlayerUIView(frame: .zero , player: viewModel.player) // if needed viewModel can be passed completely
    }

    func updateUIView(_ v: PlayerUIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    }
}

class ViewRouter : ObservableObject {
    enum Page { case home, movie }

    @Published var page = Page.home // used native publisher
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    var player: AVPlayer?

    init(frame: CGRect, player: AVPlayer?) { // player is a model so inject it here
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.player = player
        self.playerLayer.player = player
        self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("not implemented") }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var router: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if router.page == .home {
                Button(action: { self.router.page = .movie }) {
                    Text("Go to Movie")
                }
            } else if router.page == .movie {
                MovieView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The scorpion stings again! I had a bad feeling about depending on order-of-events — not very reactive or declarative. Thank you for taking the time, I spent hours stripping the example down to a "small" size. Your code works (must add environment object in `SceneDelegate`). I am studying and learning.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment "<< changes state of player" until I read in the Apple docs, about the `play()` method, "Calling this method is the same as setting the `rate` to 1.0." I.e. it's an explicit mutator.

Comment: OK it wasn't too hard to make the `PlayerModel` a `@State` variable _and_ attach an `id` to the `PlayerView`... but I thought I tried that _first_, before going all over the map and then trying it again, only to have it (seem to) behave differently. That happens with me all the time with SwiftUI. Some sort of iOS hysteresis? Or just me.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you made the `PlayerViewModel` an `ObservableObject`. That would imply sharing and modifying it; would it not be more SwiftUI-ish to make it an immutable struct, that lives and dies with its `MovieView`? As my previous comment notes, I did want to change the model while its `MovieView` stayed, but I did that by declaring it `@State` and completely replacing it. What extra benefit does `ObservableObject` bring?